Which mime type to start android GET_CONTENT to open apks files?
I want users to pick up an apks file to install.
I made an ActivityResultLauncher instance and passed application/apks to the launch() method like this.
mGetContent.launch("application/apks");

but I couldn't choose any file even if it was apks file


it was disabled.
I want all files to be disabled except for apks files.

Where are you getting this file from, and why do you think that it represents something that can be installed on an Android device?

An apks file contains the base.apk and all the other split apk files of an android app.
sometimes it contains the app icon and a json file containing some info about the app like package name but they are not necessary.
My app gets existing app apk files on the phone and compress them into apks file
